# Can't write in object's class

Tags: java, android, class, object

I have this very simple class in which I'll save data parsed from a json

```
public class WitAiOutcome {
    private String clause ="";
    private String intent = "";
    private String[] entities;

    public void setClause(String clause){
        this.clause = clause;
    }
    public void setIntent(String intent){
        this.intent = intent;
    }
    public void setEntities (String[] entities){
        this.entities = entities;
    }

    public String getClause(){
        return this.clause;
    }
    public String getIntent(){
        return this.intent;
    }
    public String[] getEntities(){
        return this.entities;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if my class is correct cause I haven't been coding since a while, but I guess this is how I'm supposed to do.

So now this is my parsing code and it works fine for my needs, I get correctly what I want, but when it comes to save the results in my object it won't work, and I don't know why... my log show no errors, it just won't print the last part where I'm "just checking".  I checked if the results where correct without setting them and everything is ok. Can someone please help me, I have no idea where I'm wrong.

```
 protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
     WitAiOutcome mOutcome = new WitAiOutcome();
     String[] entities = null;
     JSONArray root = null;
     try{
         System.out.println("##################################");
         JSONObject OutcomejObject = new JSONObject(params[0]);
         JSONObject mObject;
         JSONObject entitiesObject;

         root = OutcomejObject.getJSONArray("outcomes");
         mObject = root.getJSONObject(0);



         entitiesObject = mObject.getJSONObject("entities");
         for(int i=0;i<entitiesObject.length();i++) {
             //System.out.println(entitiesObject.names().getString(i)); //OK
             entities[i] = entitiesObject.names().getString(i);
         }

         // System.out.println(mObject.getString("_text")); //OK
         // System.out.println(mObject.getString("intent")); //OK

         mOutcome.setIntent(mObject.getString("intent"));
         mOutcome.setClause(mObject.getString("_text"));
         mOutcome.setEntities(entities);

         /**************JUST CHECKING******************/
         System.out.println(mOutcome.getClause());
         System.out.println(mOutcome.getEntities());
         entities = mOutcome.getEntities();
         for(int i=0;i<entities.length;i++)
             System.out.println(entities[i]);

     }catch(Exception e){}
     return null;
 }
```

Comment: I just found another error, it won't even set my String[] entities

Comment: Two things: your `catch` statement should be directly after your `try` block. All that `mOutcome` stuff will have to go in the `try` or after the `catch` block. Two, don't use `this` unless you need to differentiate a variable from one with the same name that's passed into a constructor, for example. While not technically _wrong_, it isn't needed and it's distracting.

Comment: Another mistake is not actually handling the exception in any way in your `catch` block. You are probably getting a JSONException or something, but you'll never know because you aren't actually checking for exceptions. Try putting `e.printStackTrace();` in your catch block and see if you are failing your `try` attempt.

Comment: A third thing, if you never intend to return anything from the class, give it a return type of `void` and just don't return anything.

Comment: So i did every thing you suggested and i'm getting  "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from null array" when trying to print from entities[]

Comment: @Frecklefoot Well, you know, that's just like your opinion, man.

Comment: Hey, you're reading from a null array because YOU DON'T HAVE A CONTRUCTOR

Comment: just solved the problem actually was String[] entities = null; instead of String[] entities = new String[entitiesObject.length()];

Comment: @m0skit0: Which statement is "my opinion"? I said three things.

Comment: @Frecklefoot Two. First one is already what OP does. Catch block must be after try, it cannot be anywhere else. Second one is your opinion.

Comment: @Lucas Today's lesson: never have empty catch blocks ;)

Comment: @m0skit0: First one: you're right. I mismatched curly braces and thought the catch was far below the try block. My mistake. Actually, it probably wouldn't even compile it he attempted to separate the try and corresponding catch block. As for the overuse of `this`, I still think it's distracting and unnecessary. Yes, it's an opinion, but one shared by most of my professors and colleagues.